# How to avoid functionality from the installed package?

Tags: visualforce, trigger, package

In my org I have objects A and B.
I have a trigger "after update" for B, that updates related A record.
It works perfectly, if update B from the B standard view.
But we have one installed package, that gives functionality to edit some fields from A and B in one custom VF page(code is hidden from me) and if I update B on this page, A is not updated - I mean, that my trigger works, in debug log I can find, that even record A was updated, but it seems that controller for this page rolls back my changes (or something like this).
I was trying to use @future - it helped but I faced other problem: my future method triggers after redirection to A record from the custom VF page, so updates is shown only after page refresh and this is not a user-friendly solution.

How can I avoid functionality from the installed package? Or maybe how to trigger update/page refresh after redirection to A record from custom VF page (I can't create custom view page for A object)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just clone page code (it is available) and write your own controller which wouldn't update object A, and use your own cloned page instead of page from managed package.

Comment: The problem here is that page code and controller code is hidden because it was installed with third-party Installed Package, so there is no way to clone it or to edit.

Comment: Please check: Page code is always visible even if it is from third-party Installed package; controller code is hidden if it belongs to managed package. But you don't need controller code; you can just guess what is inside controller and omit logic which you would like to omit.

Comment: You can mark my answer as "accepted" or upvote it this helped you to solve your question.